# How to properly use setSoTimeout to block running accept() on a socket in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, timeout

I'm struggling with sockets in Java. I need to set a **timeout** so that my process will **give up** and stop running after 1000ms. I tried following the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29), and some posts here on stackoverflow, but the process keeps waiting, blocked on the call of the `accept()` function. What am I doing wrong?

```
private static void statusRequest(String destAddr) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {    
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER2);
            serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // Blocking function
            // [... Expected working flow ...]
            // [... do some work with the received object ...]                 
        } catch (SocketException s) {
            System.out.println("No message received");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The doc you linked to is for the [`Socket.setSoTimeout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) method, which applies to `InputStream.read()`, and is separate from the [`ServerSocket.soSetTimeout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) method, which applies to `accept()`. That being said, your use of `setSoTimeout()` is fine, so if your Java system is not behaving as documented than it likely has a faulty implementation. Also, `SocketTimeoutException` does not derive from `SocketException`